# Angular Fullstack UI Router not resolving dynamic URL view. Braintree integration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, braintree

I am using yo angular-fullstack generator with uiRouter. I am integrating Braintree. I am attempting to show the API response as a confirmation page after a transaction is submitted. I can see the url in the browser for a moment and then it redirects to the home page. My initial hunch is that this is a uiRouter issue.

The four files in question:

1. server_routes
2. checkout_routes
3. client_show

I am basing my design and most of this code from [Braintree Express Example](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_express_example)

server routes:

```
'use strict';
import errors from './components/errors';
import path from 'path';
let express = require('express');
let braintree = require('braintree');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
let gateway = require('./gateway');

let TRANSACTION_SUCCESS_STATUSES = [
  braintree.Transaction.Status.Authorizing,
  braintree.Transaction.Status.Authorized,
  braintree.Transaction.Status.Settled,
  braintree.Transaction.Status.Settling,
  braintree.Transaction.Status.SettlementConfirmed,
  braintree.Transaction.Status.SettlementPending,
  braintree.Transaction.Status.SubmittedForSettlement
];

export default function(app) {
  app.use(flash());
  app.use('/api/leos', require('./api/leo'));
  app.use('/api/events', require('./api/event'));
  app.use('/api/things', require('./api/thing'));
  app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));
  app.use('/auth', require('./auth').default);
  function formatErrors(errors) {
    let formattedErrors = '';

    for (let i in errors) { // eslint-disable-line no-inner-declarations, lets-on-top
      if (errors.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        formattedErrors += 'Error: ' + errors[i].code + ': ' + errors[i].message + '\n';
      }
    }
    return formattedErrors;
  }

  function createResultObject(transaction) {
    let result;
    let status = transaction.status;

    if (TRANSACTION_SUCCESS_STATUSES.indexOf(status) !== -1) {
      result = {
        header: 'Sweet Success!',
        icon: 'success',
        message: 'Your test transaction has been successfully processed. See the Braintree API response and try again.'
      };
    } else {
      result = {
        header: 'Transaction Failed',
        icon: 'fail',
        message: 'Your test transaction has a status of ' + status + '. See the Braintree API response and try again.'
      };
    }

    return result;
  }


  // app.post('/checkout_/token', function (req, res) {
  //   gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
  //     // res.render('client/app/checkout_/checkout_', {clientToken: response.clientToken, messages: req.flash('error')});
  //   });
  // });

  app.post('/checkout/transaction/token', function (request, response) {
    gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response.json(res.clientToken);
      console.log(res.clientToken);
    });
  });

  app.post('/transaction/:id', function (req, res) {
    let result;
    let transactionId = req.params.id;

    gateway.transaction.find(transactionId, function (err, transaction) {
      result = createResultObject(transaction);
      // res.render('client/app/checkout_/checkout_/show', {transaction: transaction, result: result});
    });
  });

  app.post('/checkout', function (req, res) {
    let transactionErrors;
    let amount = req.body.amount; // In production you should not take amounts directly from clients
    let nonce = req.body.payment_method_nonce;

    gateway.transaction.sale({
      amount: amount,
      paymentMethodNonce: nonce,
      options: {
        submitForSettlement: true
      }
    }, function (err, result) {
      if (result.success || result.transaction) {
        res.redirect('transaction/' + result.transaction.id);
      } else {
        transactionErrors = result.errors.deepErrors();
        req.flash('error', {msg: formatErrors(transactionErrors)});
        res.redirect('/leos');
      }
    });
  });

  // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
    .get(errors[404]);

  // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
  app.route('/*')
    .get((req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(`${app.get('appPath')}/index.html`));
    });
}
```

checkout routes:

```
'use strict';

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';
  $stateProvider
    .state('checkout', {
      url: '/checkout',
      template: '<checkout></checkout>'
    })
    .state('transaction', {
      url: '/checkout/transaction/:id',
      template: '<transaction></transaction>'
    })
}
```

client show:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="response container">
    <div class="content">
      <section>
        <p>Test another transaction or see the Braintree API response.</p>
      </section>
      <section><a href="//checkout" class="button primary back"><span>Test Another Transaction</span></a></section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<aside class="drawer dark">
  <header>
    <div class="content compact"><a href="https://developers.braintreepayments.com" target="_blank" class="braintree">Braintree</a>
      <h3>API Response</h3>
    </div>
  </header>
  <article class="content compact">
    <section>
      <h5>Transaction</h5>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <td>{{transaction.id}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>type</th>
          <td>{{transaction.type}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>amount</th>
          <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>status</th>
          <td>{{transaction.status}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>createdAt</th>
          <td>{{transaction.createdAt}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>updatedAt</th>
          <td>{{transaction.updatedAt}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h5>Payment</h5>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>token</th>
          <td>{{transaction.creditCard.token}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>bin</th>
          <td>{{transaction.creditCard.bin}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>last4</th>
          <td>{{transaction.creditCard.last4}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>cardType</th>
          <td>{{transaction.creditCard.cardType}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>expirationDate</th>
          <td>{{expirationDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>cardholderName</th>
          <td>{{transaction.creditCard.cardholderName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>customerLocation</th>
          <td>{{transaction.creditCard.customerLocation}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h5>Customer</h5>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.id}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>firstName</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.firstName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>lastName</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.lastNam}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>email</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>company</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.company}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>website</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.website}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>phone</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>fax</th>
          <td>{{transaction.customer.fax}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
    <section>
      <p class="center small">Integrate with the Braintree SDK for a secure and seamless checkout</p>
    </section>
    <section><a href="https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in" target="_blank" class="button secondary full"> <span>See the Docs</span></a></section>
  </article>
</aside>
```